# Opencart custom module permission

Tags: php, opencart

I'm writing a module/plugin for opencart, and it would be nice to auto-create the user groups permissions.

Once the module is installed, the user must go into user permission control and manually add the permission. Its a unnecessary step, that would be very nice to jump.

As i'm currently using VqMod to do some changes (like adding extra items to the admin menu), it would be possible to add the route to the ignore route list in permission control class, but i don't think this is a nice option and i prefer to insert the permissions if possible.

I tried to add permissions with the user_group model in my constructor, but adding that to my constructor didn't work. The class is probably not instantiated before permission.

```
$this->load->model('user/user_group');

$this->model_user_user_group->addPermission($this->user->getId(), 'access', 'test/import');
$this->model_user_user_group->addPermission($this->user->getId(), 'modify', 'test/import');
```

Comment: I also noticed that the user group model does not have a function to remove permissions once you uninstall the module... Do i have to remove the permissions myself from the controller?

Comment: https://github.com/opencart/opencart/pull/693

Answer (score 1):

This code should be placed in the `install()` method of your controller. This will then be run when your mod is installed under `EXTENSIONS > MODULES` in the administrator area. Just add this to your controller and it should work (untested)

```
protected function install() {
    $this->load->model('user/user_group');

    $this->model_user_user_group->addPermission($this->user->getId(), 'access', 'test/import');
    $this->model_user_user_group->addPermission($this->user->getId(), 'modify', 'test/import');
}
```

Comment: I didnt create it as a module. I'm using my own controller type.

Comment: I'm using my own controller type. How opencart run this function in the module page if the controller has no permission to be run?

Answer (score 1):

In any case you need to create a module to add permission.

My solution is
file - controller/module/test_import.php

```
<? php  class ControllerModuleTestimport extends Controller {

    public function index() { 
        $this->redirect($this->url->link('test/import', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'));        
    }

public function install() {  
        $this->load->model('user/user_group');
        $this->model_user_user_group->addPermission($this->user->getId(), 'access', 'test/import');
        $this->model_user_user_group->addPermission($this->user->getId(), 'modify', 'test/import');
    }
} ?>
```

/language/english/module/test_import.php

```
<?php
// Heading
$_['heading_title']       = 'test_import';
?>
```

And go by link  /admin/index.php?route=extension/module/install&token=&extension=test_import

Answer (score 1):

Normally You install the module/extension from within the *modules overview*, so under ADMIN -> Extensions -> Modules. Here the user has to have `modify` permission on the `extension/modules` to be able to install/uninstall/modify the modules.

Now if the controller of Your extension has the `install` method it will be called from within `admin/controller/extension/module.php::install()` method. Anyway, You do not need to add the permission manually as they are already added by the mentioned method (check lines 115-118 of **`admin/controller/extension/module.php`**):

```
        $this->load->model('user/user_group');

        $this->model_user_user_group->addPermission($this->user->getId(), 'access', 'module/' . $this->request->get['extension']);
        $this->model_user_user_group->addPermission($this->user->getId(), 'modify', 'module/' . $this->request->get['extension']);
```

Thus IMHO, no action is needed if the new module is placed within OC's modules and is installed by normal way. If not (so it lays elsewhere) I guess You have missed something or You are not following the OC's standards or we are not talking about the extension/module then...

Comment: what if i have to create a model? there is no module folder under models folder...

Comment: @FábioSilva That's not a problem - just create such a folder and load Your model like `$this->model->load('module/mymodel');`. Then Use it like any other model: `$this->model_module_mymodel->someMethod();`.